# (Java Minecraft 1.14) How to give effects in a function rewarded by an advancement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I have a function triggered by an advancement that is supposed to give the player nausea and strength. It looks like this:

```
tellraw @s [{"text":"[","color":"dark_aqua"},{"selector":"@s","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":"] ","color":"dark_aqua"},{"text":"I feel ill...","color":"aqua"}]
effect give @s minecraft:nausea 30 3 true
effect give @s minecraft:strength 30 1 true
advancement revoke @s only dark_magic:hidden/drink_blood
```

This is triggered by the player drinking a retextured milk bucket (a blood-filled bucket), which works fine. The advancement which triggers the function is very simple and looks like this:

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "drink_blood": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:consume_item",
      "conditions": {
        "item": {
          "item": "minecraft:milk_bucket",
          "nbt": "{BloodBucket:1b,CustomModelData:1}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "dark_magic:progression/story_dialogue/i_feel_ill"
  }
}
```

When I drink a milk bucket with the custom NBT tag `BloodBucket:1b`, it works: the `/tellraw` triggers, and the advancement is revoked, reseting everything so I can drink it again and it will still work. However, the `/effect` commands don't work. I can run the function manually from the chat, as in `/function dark_magic:progression/story_dialogue/i_feel_ill`, and the effects work fine, but when run by the advancement, they don't work at all.

Does anyone know why this is? Moreover, does anyone know how to get around this? I know I could tag the player as `drank_blood` or something and `/schedule` a function for 1 tick later which executes the effects as all players tagged with `drank_blood` and removes the tag, but that seems unnecessarily complicated for something as simple as giving an effect.

Am I doing something wrong with a selector or missing something simple, or is this just not possible and I'll need to do the `/schedule` method?

Comment: `/schedule` wouldn't even help you, because it ignores all context: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-154325 What happens if you execute the function manually?

Comment: @FabianRöling If I run the function from chat, as myself, all four of the commands work as expected. From the advancement, the `/tellraw` and `/advancement` commands work, but the `/effect` ones don't. I knew that `/schedule` ignored any `/execute` instructions, but I didn't know that was unintended. I hope it gets fixed because it's pretty annoying. That is what the tag is for: to give context so it could be executed by the server and still work.

Comment: Can you make a download link for the datapack, please? That makes it easier to experiment with it, instead of having to recreate it completely.

Comment: @FabianRöling Uh sure. I'll just put the problematic files and remove the others, because there's about 50 right now. Do you have a download site you recommend?

Comment: @FabianRöling Ok so the download is [here](https://bayfiles.com/QeI0p62cna/Dark_Magic_Datapack_zip). The advancement in question is data\dark_magic\advancements\hidden\drink_blood, while the function in question is at data\dark_magic\functions\progression\story_dialogue\i_feel_ill

Comment: Alright, commands that definitely work inside that function: `/tellraw`, `/advancement`, `/bossbar`, `/clone`, `/data`, `/difficulty`, `/give`, `/experience`, `/fill`, `/gamemode`, `/gamerule`, `/kill`, `/msg`, `/particle`, `/playsound`, `/recipe`, `/replaceitem`, `/say`, `/scoreboard`, `/setblock`, `/spawnpoint`, `/summon`, `/tag`, `/team`, `/title`, `/tp`, `/weather`, `/time`, `/worldborder`. Commands that have problems: `/clear` and `/replaceitem` do not do anything with the milk bucket that I drank! Therefore I also can't test `/enchant`. Now my theory: The milk clears all effects AFTER …

Comment: … the function ran. Therefore you first get the effects and then they are immediately cleared. And then the game tries to remove the milk bucket (but in my adjusted function it's already cleared) and puts an empty bucket there. So the order of execution is just weird, this might be a bug. Also: Wow, how could we both not think about this. It's MILK, it should have been obvious to at least me that this could be related. Yet I needed to test all these commands and notice the weirdness with `/clear` before I got the idea (while writing this comment). Edit: I guess this is not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long search for the cause, a short and simple answer:

Functions that are rewards for an advancement triggered by the `consume_item` trigger are executed before the item does what it does. For example your function first gives its effects to you, THEN the milk bucket clears all effects and the empty bucket it put into its slot.

Comment: Ok. I'll probably just tag the player as having drank the bucket and schedule a function to give all players with that tag the effects one tick later and remove the tag. Thanks for the help!